# turn off special video mode for Safari iOS

Tags: html, ios, safari, html5-video, mobile-safari

When I start a video with Safari, a special full-screen mode comes up. Can I disable or style this?

```html
<video src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4"></video>
```

Screenshot (iPhone 13 iOS v15.5 from Browserstack):

[image: iPhone 13 iOS v15.5 from Browserstack]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the answer here: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

On iPhone, `<video playsinline>` elements will now be allowed to play inline, and will not automatically enter fullscreen mode when playback begins.